# How do I combine Wordpress with Ultimate Member and Media Library Folders in the following ways

Tags: wordpress

I need to know if it's possible to use these plugins to solve my problem or if I need to do something else to get the result that I want.

I use two plugins:

1. Ultimate Members
2. Media Library Folder

I need people to be able to register and when they do it creates a folder with their name - it can be when they start putting in images, too.

When they have an item, in this case a car, they go to a form and create a new item, and they add information. When they add images it creates a directory in their user folder matching that form name - and adds the images to that directory.

```
User 1 
- Car1
-----Image1
-----Image2
-----Image3
- Car2
-----Image4
-----Image5
-----Image6
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIZx9.png)

I have tryed to solve this for weeks but no luck =/

Comment: _"Just negative people give negative score."_ - wrong. This question will get down voted because it's asking for solutions without demonstrating what you've tried. Have you tried anything to get this to work?

Comment: Of Course i have tried for weeks, but i cant find a solution, i want to solve this with Wordpress but i cant find the way. It might be an other plugin out there i havent found that solve the problem

Comment: I'm sure you've tried, but WHAT did you try? Just telling us you tried something, doesn't help. Where are you specifically stuck? Where is the code you've attempted - even if it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

We've used Formidable Forms Pro to create a system similar to what you describe.

You can use Formidable Forms to register users and create a user page/portal for that user. Users can have the ability to create more than one page, or submit the form with the car image and information multiple times.

I believe you can customize the location the images are saved in, but, by default, he images the user uploads won't be in a separate folder, but they will be attached to that user. Additionally, you can add restrictions to limit who can access the images. You can restrict visibility of the post to.

Customization would require being able to modify the sample code provided by Formidable Forms.

I would suggest contacting Formidable for more information; they have excellent support: http://formidableforms.com/